# Disabling JCrop on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm trying to disable the JCrop functionality on document load. I tried placing a `disable()` function in my document.ready function, but it seems it does not disable JCrop.

My Syntax is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jcrop_api.disable();

});
```

How do I disable the JCrop on document load, and if ever I want to enable it again, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var jcrop_api;
function initJcrop() {
    jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#cropbox');
}
//destroy JCrop
function destroyJCrop(){
   jcrop_api.destroy();
}
//rehook JCrop
function hookJCrop(){
    initJcrop();
}
```

Documentation: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=advanced

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(window).load(function() {`

```
$(window).load(function() {
   jcrop_api.disable();
});
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() {
    jcrop_api.destroy();
});
```

> destroy() Remove Jcrop entirely
>
> crop can also be completely removed from the image

---

> The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while
>   the onload event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has
>   been loaded.

---

Reference

[Jcrop_API](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_API.html)

Read [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)